# How can I display an SSRS report in an Angular Application?

Tags: angular, reporting-services

We are migrating a report from a WindowsForm application to an Angular Web Application.

The WindowsForm uses the ReportViewer to display the report on the screen, so I searched for an alternative for it on Angular and found the [ngx-ssrs-reportviewer](https://github.com/tycomo/ngx-ssrs-reportviewer) package.
It looks like exactly what I need, so I followed the instructions to install it and included it on my modules file, had to install some packages that were reported as missing (@angular/elements and @webcomponents/custom-elements) but when I run 'ng serve' I ran into this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../../../src/app/app.module.ts:47)
    at Object.../../../../../src/app/app.module.ts (main.bundle.js:244)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../../../src/main.ts:4)
    at Object.../../../../../src/main.ts (main.bundle.js:940)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at Object.0 (main.bundle.js:962)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (inline.bundle.js:26)
```

I've Googled this error but I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

### The Configuration

Here is the app.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ReportViewerModule } from "ngx-ssrs-reportviewer";
// Many other imports

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    // Many other components
  ],
  imports: [
    ReportViewerModule,
    // Many other modules
  ],
  providers: [//Services here],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule {
 }
```

Here is the package version of the components:

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.0
Node: 12.13.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.1.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.0
@angular/elements: 10.0.4
@angular/language-service: 4.4.6
@angular/material: 5.2.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.36
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.42
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.0
@schematics/angular: 0.1.11
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.11
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.10.0

@webcomponents/custom-elements: ^1.4.2
ngx-ssrs-reportviewer: ^2.0.7
```

Does anyone know how can I make the package work on the project or what others alternatives can be used to display a report on a web application?

Comment: Have you considered embedding an iframe to the report on your report server? You can use URL parameters to make it full-screen etc.

Comment: @StevenWhite, could you explain a bit more about embedding an iframe? I would use an iframe on the front-end to display the data that the report server would send, is that correct? Would the back-end need an endpoint, an API to send the data?